# Oracle Specific Sorting

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following problem:
I need to sort some products where one needs to be a specific row and others to be random.

So if I have products: `A B C D`, I need for example B to be the third product while others can be random like:

```
C  1
A  2
B  3
D  4
```

Best shot I have tried is (3 is a dynamic value):

```
SELECT
    product_name,
    CASE
        WHEN product = 'B' THEN 3
        ELSE ( CASE WHEN rownum < 3 THEN rownum ELSE rownum + 1 END )
    END sorting
FROM
    products
ORDER BY
    sorting ASC;
```

but I'm not always getting the desired outcome.

Any help or lead is appreciated.

Comment: Where in your query are you using random numbers? Where/how is `rownum` defined or generated?

Comment: Tip: You don't need to use a nested `CASE WHEN`:  you can make `rownum < 3` the second case in the top `CASE WHEN` expression.

Comment: By random I mean that is not important how other products are sorted. I only want them to be in between 1 - no. of products where one of the rows is specified by me. I hope I'm clear.

Comment: @ErgiNushi . . . This is a genuinely interesting question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather tricky, but you can use `row_number()` and a bunch of arithmetic:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (order by case when product = 'B' then 2 else 1 end),
                                         dbms_random.value
                               ) as seqnum
      from products p
     ) p
order by (case when seqnum < 3 then seqnum end),
         (case when product = 'B' then 1 else 2 end),
         seqnum;
```

The logic is:

- Enumerate the values randomly, with the special value going last.
- Put in the rows with lower values.
- Put in the row with the special value.
- Put in the rest of the rows.

The above uses a subquery because the randomness is enforced.  You can do this without a subquery as:

```
order by (case when row_number() over (order by (case when product = 'B' then 2 else 1 end) < 3
               then dbms_random.value
               else 2  -- bigger than value
          end),
         (case when product = 'B' then 1 else 2 end),
         dbms_random.value;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Randomness is not enforced in fact. I only need that the specific product to be in the specific place I imply. Other products can be in a random order in between 1 - no. of products I have. Like I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @ErgiNushi . . . That is not an important part of this answer, but your question does specific say "random", so I included it.

Comment: After making a few changes this worked perfectly. Thank you very much :D